# Em que circunstâncias um usuário é notificado ao ser mencionado no chat?

Tags: suporte, notificações, chat

Ontem [uma sala de chat foi criada](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22914/test) e eu fui mencionado com `@mgibsonbr` mas nenhuma notificação apareceu pra mim [agora que entrei de novo] de que alguém havia me chamado. Por que? Lembro que na [sala principal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) eu sempre era notificado - no entanto, era comum eu já ter postado lá antes.

Em que circunstâncias a notificação ocorre? É preciso que se esteja online para isso acontecer (ou talvez se você estiver offline a notificação acontece, mas depois desaparece após algum tempo)?

Comment: Quando abro chat com alguém as notificações me chegam. Entrei na sala e mencionei você, veja se notificou.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Não, nada...

Comment: Uma restrição que conheço é que você não pode notificar pessoas em uma sala que elas nunca visitaram antes. Você já havia visitado esta sala antes de ser notificado?

Comment: @VictorStafusa De fato, não.

Answer (score 6):

Você não pode notificar pessoas em uma sala que elas nunca visitaram antes.

Como você não havia visitado esta sala anteriormente, você não recebeu as notificações.

As razões para isso, especulo eu, são as seguintes:

- Evitar spam, que seria possível se alguém criasse uma sala de chat qualquer e saísse notificando todo mundo.
- Evitar notificações indevidas. Afinal, se eu postar `@Joe` em alguma sala de chat qualquer, então provavelmente apenas o Joe que estiver lá presente (ou que esteve no passado) é relevante e os demais Joe's na rede Stack Exchange não deveriam ser incomodados.

Conforme explicado pelo @bfavaretto, há ainda dois casos especiais:

- Em caso de conversas em comentários migradas para chat, os participantes anteriores da conversa (nos comentários) são notificáveis no chat.
- Moderadores têm um recurso de um super-ping que permite notificar qualquer usuário em qualquer sala.

---

Realizei um teste agora há pouco. No chat, ao digitar `@b`, apenas o bigown foi sugerido. Mesmo assim eu preenchi com `@bfavaretto` e o nosso amigo moderador NÃO FOI notificado. Isso demonstra que provavelmente também há algum limite de tempo para notificar um usuário que esteve presente no chat no passado e não voltou mais até então.

Comment: Não sei se será só isso. Acho que uma explicação completa dos moderadores seria o ideal.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ok, posso até especular os motivos para isso, tais como evitar spam ou evitar que ao colocar `@Joe` em qualquer sala, que um monte de gente que nada tem a ver com o que se passa lá acabe sendo notificada. Mas até aqui são só especulações.

Comment: Se a pessoa fica muito tempo sem acessar o chat o nome dela some da lista de pessoas "notificáveis", mas não sei quanto é esse tempo. Para comprovar, tentem notificar o brasofilo lá, já vi muito ele por lá mas ele anda sumido e o nome dele já não está mais "notificável". PS: Será que eu posso abrir um tópico no meta perguntando "Por onde anda o brasofilo?" ?

Comment: @Math Eu acho que a pessoa continua notificável. O caso do brasofilo é que ele provavelmente não viu a notificação, ou não quer responder. Você pode até perguntar sobre ele no meta, mas a única pessoa que poderia responder com segurança sobre o paradeiro dele seria ele próprio, e ele está sumido. Podemos chamar de "paradoxo do brasofilo" :)

Comment: @bfavaretto o que eu quis dizer com "notificável" é que o autocomplete do chat não mostra ele como opção, então eu supus que ele não recebe a notificação nesse caso, mas para ter certeza precisaríamos fazer um teste que não seria dos mais fáceis de fazer, ou procurar algo oficial no MetaSE.

Comment: @Math Ah, entendi. Realmente não tenho certeza sobre como isso funciona.

Comment: @bfavaretto Te notifiquei no chat. Você recebeu a notificação?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não!

Comment: Está explicado porque fiquei no vácuo várias vezes aguardando outra pessoa responder.